# I want to add custom option in NetSuite

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

Now, I'm in a course of learning NetSuite.
My task is to add custom option in Sales Order Record.
I tried this using UserEvent script but it doesn't work.

```
if(context.form && context.type == context.UserEventType.EDIT) {
    var currentForm = context.form;
        
    currentForm.addField({
        id: 'custpage_paymentoption',
        type: 'SELECT',
        label: 'Custom Payment Option',
        container : 'paymentmethod'
    });
    currentForm.addSelectOption({
        value: 'card1',
        text:  'Card1',
    });
    currentForm.addSelectOption({
        value: 'card2',
        text:  'Card2',
    });
    currentForm.addSelectOption({
        value: 'card2',
        text:  'Card2',
    });
}
```

I'm not sure this is script issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Remove container value in addField().
2. Use insertSelectOption() instead of addSelectOption().

Hope this advice is helpful for you.